# Is there a way to force run all specs with guard + guard-rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, guard

Is there something similar to autotest's ctrl+c to force run all specs?  I'm still working to fine tune my .Guardfile, but for the time being can I force run all specs without restarting guard?  ctrl+c quits guard.

Comment: The selected answer is now out of date.

Answer (score 26):

The posix signals that Mark suggests are no longer used to interact with guard. See the section titled "Interactions" in the [README](https://github.com/guard/guard) for the new way to interact.

To trigger each guard's `run_all` method, just hit enter in the guard terminal. To trigger rspec's `run_all` method, type `rspec` and hit enter.

Comment: can I do something like this when I do any change in my spec or code from rails apps it triggers its run_all method ?

Answer (score 17):

https://github.com/guard/guard#interactions

You can interact with Guard and enter commands when Guard has nothing to do. Guard understands the following commands:

```
↩: Run all Guards.
h, help: Show a help of the available interactor commands.
r, reload: Reload all Guards.
n, notification: Toggle system notifications on and off.
p, pause: Toggles the file modification listener. The prompt will change to p> when paused. This is useful when switching Git branches, rebase Git or change whitespace.
e, exit: Stop all Guards and quit Guard.
```

So, basically you go into the terminal where Guard is running and hit enter/return.

Comment: I just went back over this and noticed that @balexand had already given much the same answer. I didn't notice his answer at first, positioned as it was subordinate to an ad. There ought to be something to be done when the accepted answer is wrong (or as in this case, out of date). I attempted an edit of the accepted answer, but it was rejected...ah well...this sort of thing has probably been discussed (no doubt at length) on meta.

Comment: this what I was looking for thanks. therefore by simply adding `r` to guard it reloads and runs all tests. eg: `[5] guard(main)> r`. Now I wonder if there's a way to add a shortcukey that will trigger `guard(main)> r` from sublime-text 2?

Answer (score 4):

Probably the easiest thing to do is [use Spork](http://railscasts.com/episodes/285-spork), then simplify your Guardfile:

```
# Guardfile
guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :cli => '--drb' do # :cli => is important!
  watch(%r{^spec/}) { "spec" }
  watch(%r{^app/}) { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb') { "spec" }
end
```

This will run anything in the `spec` folder when anything in the `spec`, `app`, or `routes.rb` changes, as soon as you save it, and will save you a ton of time.

Use the `growl` (mac) or `libnotify` (linux) gems to get pop-up notifications. Then you just code in your editor, and shortly after each save you'll get a pop-up pass / fail notification. If it's a pass you just keep on coding -- if it's a fail you pop over to the terminal and check out what the error is.

Comment: couldn't agree more. spork is a great tool to add to your TDD toolbox.